# Issues with xpath that contained namespaces in Java (Dom parser)

Tags: java, parsing, dom, rdfs

I'm trying to parse an rdfs xml file in order to find all the Classes in an rdfs file.

The xpath: "/rdf:RDF/rdfs:Class"
is working in my XML editor.
When i insert the xpath in my Java program (i have implemented a dom parser), i get 0 Classes.
The following example runs but it outputs 0 classes!

I do:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) throws XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{

    FindClasses FSB = new FindClasses();
    FSB.FindAllClasses("C:\\Workspace\\file.xml"); //rdfs file
     }
}
```

The class FindClasses is as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class FindClasses {

public void FindAllClasses(String fileName) throws XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {


    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(fileName);

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression classes_expr = xpath.compile("/rdf:RDF/rdfs:Class");

    Object result = classes_expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList classes = (NodeList) result;

    System.out.println("I found : " + classes.getLength() + " classes " );

        }
    }
```

The rdfs file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xml:lang="en" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
        <rdfs:Class rdf:about="Class1">
        </rdfs:Class>
        <rdfs:Class rdf:about="Class2">
        </rdfs:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I don't really understand why the xpath returns 0 nodes in that example.
It's weird, cause i have implemented other dom parsers as well and they were working fine.
Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I visited the following link and i solved my problem:
**[Issues with xpath in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027634/issues-with-xpath-in-java)**

The problem was that the xpath contained two namespaces (rdf,rdfs) like "/rdf:RDF/rdfs:Class".
If the xpath didn't contain any namespace e.g. /RDF/Class , there was not going to be an issue.

So  **after** the line:

```
xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
```

and **before** the line:

```
XPathExpression classes_expr = xpath.compile("/rdf:RDF/rdfs:Class");
```

I **added** the following:

```
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
      switch (prefix) {
        case "rdf": return "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#";
        case "rdfs" : return "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"; 
       }
    return prefix;

    }
    public String getPrefix(String namespace) {
        if (namespace.equals("rdf")) return "rdf";
        else if (namespace.equals("rdfs")) return "rdfs";
        else return null;
       }
    @Override
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    });
```

Comment: If you don't want to go to the trouble of implementing `NamespaceContext` yourself, there's a useful general-purpose implementation [provided by the Spring framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/util/xml/SimpleNamespaceContext.html)